# Analytic solution to an equation including the error function in Maxima

Tags: maxima

Maxima does not seem to come up with an analytic solution to this equation which includes the error function. The independent variable here is "p" and the dependent variable to be solved for is "x".

[see an illustration of equation follow link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XG57.png)

```
(%i3)   solveexplicit:true$ ratprint:false$ fpprintprec:6$
(%i4)   eqn: (sqrt(%pi)*(25*2^(3/2)*p-25*sqrt(2))*erf(1/(25*2^(3/2)*x))*x+1)/(25*p) = 0.04;
(%i5)   solve (eqn, x);
(%o5)   []
(%i6)   eqn, [p=2,x=0.00532014],numer;
(%o6)   0.04=0.04
```

Any help or pointing in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Maxima can't solve equations containing `erf`. You can get a numerical result via `find_root`:

```
(%i5) find_root (eqn, x, 0.001, 0.999), p=2;
(%o5)               0.005320136894034347
```

As for symbolic solutions, I worked with the equation a little bit. One can get it into the form `erf(something/x)*x = otherstuff`, or equivalently `erf(y) = somethingelse*y` where `y = something/x` and `somethingelse = otherstuff/something` if I'm not mistaken. I don't know anything in particular about equations of that form, but perhaps you can find something.

Comment: I also played with that and substituted `y=1/(25*2^1,5*x)` but with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, solve can only do polynominals. I used the series expansion for small values of x and the accuracy is good enough.

```
(%i11)  seriesE: 1$  
        termE: erf(x)$  
        for p: 1 unless p > 3 do  
                  (termE: diff (termE, x)/p,   
                   seriesE: seriesE + subst (x=0, termE)*x^p)$  
        seriesE;  

(%o11)  -(2*x^3)/(3*sqrt(%pi))+(2*x)/sqrt(%pi)+1
```

However, the "Expression longer than allowed by the configuration setting!"